RF coil is a capacitor
I have a coil, and I want to measure its inductance, however, for frequencies below 500 MHz, it shows capacitive behavior.
Is this a calibration error, or is it normal for a coil like this?
What should I do to ensure the coil behaves inductively at frequencies like 433 MHz?

Second image in range up to 500 MHz

If I add 50 Ohm resistance parallel - the graph will show something like right - inductance, but does it will be correct for measuring?


You might just have a really low self-resonant frequency; this inductor doesn't appear to be wound properly for wideband operation. Set your VNA to show you more resolution in the 0 to 500 MHz range.

i have added image with bigger resolution

Your first image (starting at 50 kHz) shows a point at $S_{11}=-1$ but it's gone from the 2nd and 3rd images (which start at 26 MHz). Try plotting the band from .05 - 1 MHz or .05 - 10 MHz and see if you get a helpful result. If your VNA allows it, use a logarithmic spaced frequency sweep instead of linear.

i have added 50 kHz - 540 MHz

In addition to @ThePhoton 's comments, a few of the 101 data points of photo#2 are outside S11 circle, which suggests perhaps your VNA should be recalibrated at the lower-frequency end of its range. At 550 MHz, those long inductor leads become significant - you might cut them shorter to get closer to the reference plane.

Keep in mind that a network analyzer compares the the DUT impedance to 50 ohms. So impedances very different from 50 ohms cannot be measured accurately. (Although S11 shows a scale down to -70 dB, I would not believe anything smaller than -30 dB or so, even if carefully calibrated. S21 is different, transmitted power of -60 db or so is resolvable). You should START by estimating the impedance of your device (coil). Don't even bother measuring at frequencies where that impedance is very far from 50 ohms.
Those small blips may be resonances (or maybe not). High resolution measurements around them may reveal some structure.

Do I understand correctly that once I figure out the resistance of the coil, I should then add resistance to make it, for example, 50 ohms, and only after that measure the impedance?

No. Estimate the inductance of the coil using approximate formulas you can find on the web. Measure at a frequency where the inductive impedance is not too far from 50 ohms. Calibrate the nanoVNA carefully.
